# Bash: For all groups, find owned files

Tags: bash, pipe, user-permissions

I want to run `find /path1 -group group1` but for all of the groups.

The concept could be something like this:
`groups > array1 | for i in array1 do find /path1 -group array[i]`

Comment: I would turn this around and list all the files under that path with a custom format of `[group] [filename]` and then use awk to split that into individual files per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-ls` with `find` to list the file information, then use `awk` to redirect the output to files based on the `group` value (column 6):

`find /path -ls | awk '{ print $0 >> "group_"$6".txt"; }'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in a loop with *process substitution*:

```
while read -d' ' -r g; do
    find . -group "$g"
done < <(groups)
```

Comment: Why process substitution and not a simple _pipe_: `groups | while...`

Comment: Pipe forks loop in a sub shell while `process substitution` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. One more thing I learned today!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run **find /path1 -group group1** but for all of the groups.

You can have it in one instance of `find` with:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -a GRPS < <(exec groups)
ARGS=()
for G in "${GRPS[@]}"; do
    ARGS+=("-o" "-group" "$G")
done
ARGS=('(' "${ARGS[@]:1}" ')')

find /path1 "${ARGS[@]}"
```

If you try to do `echo find /path1 "${ARGS[@]}"`, it would show something like:

```
find /path1 ( -group root -o -group bin -o -group daemon -o -group sys -o -group adm )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
find /path -group group1 -or -group2
```

or

```
for i in group1 group2 ; do find /path1 -group $i ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what groups own the file, you can find all files owned by any recognized group by using:

```
find /path ! -nogroup
```

Which will list all files with a recognized owner group ID.

If you want to order them by their group ownership, use this:

```
find /path -printf '%g:%f\n' |sort
```

Which will output lines like this:

```
root:.bashrc
users:userfiles
```